# Alias in .bash_aliases executes incorrectly

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias, awk

I have an alias in .bash_aliases and it gives me incorrect output when I trigger it.

```
alias print="echo a b | awk '{print $2}'"
```

incorrect output:

```
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ print
a b
```

expected output:

```
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ echo a b | awk '{print $2}'
b
```

other information:

```
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ cat ~/.bashrc | grep 'alias print'
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ cat ~/.bash_aliases | grep 'alias print'
alias print="echo a b | awk '{print $2}'"
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ alias | grep 'alias print'
alias print='echo a b | awk '\''{print }'\'''
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ print
a b
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ echo a b | awk '{print $2}'
b
slazer@ubuntu:~/Desktop/xpalenik_pb161/hw03/examples/extra$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I have not installed all the updates. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` to prevent it being expanded by the shell; since it expands to nothing, your alias becomes equivalent to

```
alias print="echo a b | awk '{print }'"
```

Try instead

```
alias print="echo a b | awk '{print \$2}'"
```

Comment: Tx it works. I have UNALIASed the print, indeed.

Comment: @muru Doh! you're right of course - I really shouldn't post before coffee ;)